# Rails console: attribute returns false, but is shown correctly with to_yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, db2, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

maybe I'm missing something, but I did research and could not find out why this is behaving like it does. I'm working with Rails 2.3.16 and ruby 1.9.3, backed by a huge ibm-db2.

Lets assume I have a class Foo (I tried to build a short example here)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The class has attributes: phone (integer) and mail (string).

When I use the Rails console to debug

```
bundle exec ./script/console      , or
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec ./script/console
```

I can load a Foo instance by doing:

```
f = Foo.find_by_phone(123)
=> #<Foo phone: false, mail: "test@example.org">
```

If I try to use the getter-method to get the `phone`-attribute:

```
f.phone
=> false
```

But the information must be there, because rails i) found the object and ii) you could do this yaml-output:

```
y f
---- !ruby/object:Foo
attributes: 
 phone: 123
 mail: test@example.org
attributes_cache: {}
```

**Thanks guys** for helping me in advance, I'm sure I overlooked something!

Comment: what does `Foo.phone_before_type_cast` look like, and what does the schema for the Table look like?

Comment: Do you have attr_accessor for phone in your class?

Comment: @Doon: NoMethodError: undefined method `phone_before_type_cast' for ...
@megas: no for both. I tried adding attr_accessor :phone, then f.phone returnes nil, while the yaml version stays the same.

Comment: @muistooshort:

create_table "foo", :id => false, :force => true do |t|

    t.integer :phone

    t.string :mail
end

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be, that ActiveRecord interprets the DB2 short type as boolean. Is it possible to change that (stupid?) behavior?